# Spring session with redis - lost Principal

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-session

guys.
I migrated to Spring session with Redis implementation. I'm using spring boot and the only thing that i've made to start with this implementation is to add this

```
    <!-- Spring Session with Redis -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- -->
```

in pom.xml and this in application.properties.

```
#Redis for session persistent
spring.session.store-type=REDIS
spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.data.redis.repositories.enabled=false
```

Everything is working fine, except that from time to time, the Principal (authneticated user is lost). I still have access to restricted pages, but Principal obejct is null. This leads to corrupted data, because I track the entries created from the speceific user.

Whan of the methods that have problem is:

```
public void addSamples(Integer distributorId, String articleNumber, Integer quantity, Principal user) {
     Distributor distributor = distributorRepository.getOne(distributorId);
     Tile tile = tileRepository.findByArticleNumber(articleNumber);
     Merchandiser merchandiser = merchandiserRepository.findByUsername(user.getName());

     Samples samples = new Samples();
     samples.setMerchandiser(merchandiser);
     samples.getSamplesPK().setDistributor(distributor);
     samples.getSamplesPK().setTile(tile);
     samples.setQuantity(quantity);

     distributor.getSamples().add(samples);
     distributorRepository.save(distributor);
 }
```

I'm still logged and have access, but the merchandiser object is null..

What can be the reason for this ? Any help will be usefull.

Best regards.